# Android TextView cannot setBackground Color or Drawable

Tags: android, textview, setbackground

wonder if anyone has came across this problem before.  I have an app which detects faces and places touchable squares around the faces, all in a RelativeLayout.  When touched I want to add some text into the View which is all working nicely, but when I go to simply add a background to the TextView it just does nothing.  I've tried a standard background `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` instead of the background I really want to use (`setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nametag);`) and still nothing.

```
TextView nameLabelView = new TextView(activity);
nameLabelView.setText(fullname);
nameLabelView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
nameLabelView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                 //TODO <-- wth??
//nameLabelView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nametag);
nameLabelView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

//duplicate layout params from active face View so label sits inside it
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = selectedFaceView.getLayoutParams();
nameLabelView.setLayoutParams(lp);
facePreviewLayout.addView(nameLabelView);
```

Strange one, hope it's obvious to someone out there, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works ok for me. It is necessary to provide more information so I can help more with it. The code below works fine.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView nameLabelView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        nameLabelView.setText("Test");
        nameLabelView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        nameLabelView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);                 //TODO <-- wth??
        //nameLabelView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nametag);
        nameLabelView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        //duplicate layout params from active face View so label sits inside it
        FrameLayout selectedFaceView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = selectedFaceView.getLayoutParams();
        nameLabelView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        RelativeLayout facePreviewLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        facePreviewLayout.addView(nameLabelView);

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you `janzoner` for your test really appreciate it, good to know I wasn't going mad.  I've found a way to work around it though, I have no idea why this method works and the setup I had before didn't, perhaps I'd been staring at it too long and missed something somewhere else.

Basically beforehand I was adding the name label `TextView` into the main `RelativeLayout` (whose children were the actual image and all the face `Views` etc).

Now I have moved the name label `TextView` into its own `RelativeLayout` which sits around the face, and that's magically done the trick.  This is a cleaner way of doing things anyway as you can't iterate through child `Views` of `Views` but you can children of `RelativeLayout`'s and I will need this later!

Phew!

Comment: There is still a lot of room for improvement :)